# Download Plot Using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The Rest of the app is working but not able to download the plots. I want to include a download button in my app for plots- both png & pdf files. I have the following code, when I push the download button I dont get option to save in the desired format. Can anyone see where the error is:

ui.R part with downloadbutton:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage( 
  titlePanel(title = h4("Business Intelligence & Analytics", align="center")), 
    sidebarLayout(  
      sidebarPanel(("Make Selections Here"),
                   textInput("name","Enter your name",""),
                   textInput("Age","Enter Age",""),
      radioButtons("Gender","Enter Gender",list("Male","Female")),
     sliderInput("Slider","Select The Value", min = 0, max = 100, value = 4, animate = T,
                 step = 5),  
    selectInput("State","Name Of The States",c("California","Arizona",
                                               "Chicago","Rosemont","Dallas")
                ,selected = "Dallas",selectize = TRUE, multiple = TRUE ), 
    selectizeInput("Variable","Select the Var",
        c("Sepal.Length"=1,"Sepal.Width"=2,"Petal.Width"=3)),
    sliderInput("Bins","Select The Number Of Bins",min = 5, max=20,value = 2),
    radioButtons("Colour","Select The Colour",list("Green","Yellow","Red","Black"),
                 selected = "Yellow"),
    radioButtons("Download Option", "Select the Option", list("png","jpeg","pdf"))),

      mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type="tab", #adding tab sheets 
                  tabPanel("Summary",verbatimTextOutput("Cat9")),
                  tabPanel("Structure", verbatimTextOutput("Cat8")), #verbatim TextOutput used to show output of render print
                  tabPanel("Data",tableOutput("Cat7")),
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("Cat6"))
                  ),
        textOutput("Cat1"),
        textOutput("Cat2"),
        textOutput("Cat3"), 
        textOutput("Cat4"),
        textOutput("Cat5"), 
      plotOutput("hist"),
      downloadButton(outputId = "Cat10", label = "Download The Plot")

              ) 
      )
)
)
```

Code for Server.R Part:

```
shinyServer(  function(input, output){   output$Cat1 <- 
renderText(input$name)   output$Cat2 <- renderText(input$Age) 
output$Cat3<- renderText(input$Gender)
output$Cat4 <- renderText(paste("You Selected The Value:", input$Slider))
output$Cat5 <- renderText(input$State)
output$Cat6<- renderPlot({
 colm <- as.numeric(input$Variable)
 hist(iris[,colm], breaks =seq(0,max(iris[,colm]),l=input$Bins+1), 
      col = input$Colour, main = "Histogram Of Iris",xlab = 
names(iris[colm]))

output$Cat7 = renderTable({

  head(iris,4)

}) 

output$Cat8 = renderPrint({
str(iris3) 

})   output$Cat9 <- renderPrint({summary(iris3)
})
 output$Cat10<- downloadHandler(
#Specify The File Name 
filename = function() {
paste("iris",input$`Download Option`,sep= ".") 
 #here we are downloading in format we have mentoned in download option in 
ui.r #this could be pdf png etc and paste iris means the output will create 
a file which will have the name of the dataset in our case iris followed by 
the format we want it to be in and their naming convention is seperated by a 
.},
content = function(file){
# open the format of file which needs to be downloaded ex: pdf, png etc. 
if (input$`Download Option`== "png")
png(file)
#else if (input$`Download Option`== "pdf")
#pdf(file)
else jpeg(file)
hist(iris[,colm], breaks =seq(0,max(iris[,colm]),l=input$Bins+1), 
     col = input$Colour, main = "Histogram Of Iris",xlab = 
names(iris[colm]))

dev.off()
}
) 
}
```

Comment: Are you trying the download button in Shiny's viewer? Download button for Shiny works ONLY when you open the app in your browser.

Comment: This was the miss, i tried the same code in browser and it worked handsomely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assigned your variable "colm" inside a render function and tried to access it in the downloadHandler. This works for me:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  titlePanel(title = h4("Business Intelligence & Analytics", align="center")), 
  sidebarLayout(  
    sidebarPanel(("Make Selections Here"),
                 textInput("name","Enter your name",""),
                 textInput("Age","Enter Age",""),
                 radioButtons("Gender","Enter Gender",list("Male","Female")),
                 sliderInput("Slider","Select The Value", min = 0, max = 100, value = 4, animate = T,
                             step = 5),  
                 selectInput("State","Name Of The States",c("California","Arizona",
                                                            "Chicago","Rosemont","Dallas")
                             ,selected = "Dallas",selectize = TRUE, multiple = TRUE ), 
                 selectizeInput("Variable","Select the Var",
                                c("Sepal.Length"=1,"Sepal.Width"=2,"Petal.Width"=3)),
                 sliderInput("Bins","Select The Number Of Bins",min = 5, max=20,value = 2),
                 radioButtons("Colour","Select The Colour",list("Green","Yellow","Red","Black"),
                              selected = "Yellow"),
                 radioButtons("Download Option", "Select the Option", list("png","jpeg","pdf"))),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type="tab", #adding tab sheets 
                  tabPanel("Summary",verbatimTextOutput("Cat9")),
                  tabPanel("Structure", verbatimTextOutput("Cat8")), #verbatim TextOutput used to show output of render print
                  tabPanel("Data",tableOutput("Cat7")),
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("Cat6"))
      ),
      textOutput("Cat1"),
      textOutput("Cat2"),
      textOutput("Cat3"), 
      textOutput("Cat4"),
      textOutput("Cat5"), 
      plotOutput("hist"),
      downloadButton(outputId = "Cat10", label = "Download The Plot")

    ) 
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  colm <- reactive({as.numeric(input$Variable)})

  output$Cat1 <- renderText(input$name)
  output$Cat2 <- renderText(input$Age) 
  output$Cat3<- renderText(input$Gender)
  output$Cat4 <- renderText(paste("You Selected The Value:", input$Slider))
  output$Cat5 <- renderText(input$State)
  output$Cat6<- renderPlot({
    hist(iris[,colm()], breaks =seq(0,max(iris[,colm()]),l=input$Bins+1), 
         col = input$Colour, main = "Histogram Of Iris",xlab = 
           names(iris[colm()]))
  })

  output$Cat7 = renderTable({

    head(iris,4)

  }) 

  output$Cat8 = renderPrint({
    str(iris3) 

  })   

  output$Cat9 <- renderPrint({summary(iris3)
  })

  output$Cat10<- downloadHandler(
    #Specify The File Name 
    filename = function() {
      paste("iris",input$`Download Option`,sep= ".")},
    content = function(file){
      # open the format of file which needs to be downloaded ex: pdf, png etc. 
      if (input$`Download Option`== "png"){
        png(file)
      } else if (input$`Download Option`== "pdf"){
        pdf(file)
      } else {
        jpeg(file) 
      }
      hist(iris[,colm()], breaks =seq(0,max(iris[,colm()]),l=input$Bins+1), 
           col = input$Colour, main = "Histogram Of Iris",xlab = 
             names(iris[colm()]))

      dev.off()
    }
  )
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```